# Why won't my SelectedIndexChanged event fire in Button_Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow tb = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();

    DropDownList db = new DropDownList();
    db.Items.Add("Bangalore");
    db.Items.Add("Mandya");
    db.Items.Add( "Hassan");

    tc.Controls.Add(db);
    tb.Controls.Add(tc);

    Table1.Controls.Add(tb);

    db.SelectedIndexChanged += db_SelectedIndexChanged;
    db.AutoPostBack = true;
}

private void db_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.text = "welcome";
}
```

When this code executes in the `Button1_Click` event, `db_SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't execute. However, when I place the same `Button1_Click` code block in the `Page_Load` event, `db_SelectedIndexChanged` executes.

What may be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put

```
db.SelectedIndexChanged += db_SelectedIndexChanged;
db.AutoPostBack = true;
```

In the Page_Load event.

Don't wrap db.SelectedIndexChanged += db_SelectedIndexChanged; in !Page.IsPostBack as the events need to be wired up on each load

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a dynamic control. The event will not fire unless you create the control in the `PreInit` method of the page.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList db = new DropDownList();
    db.Items.Add("Bangalore");
    db.Items.Add("Mandya");
    db.Items.Add( "Hassan");
    db.SelectedIndexChanged += db_SelectedIndexChanged;
    db.AutoPostBack = true;

    tc.Controls.Add(db);
}
```

Check [Page Life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     TableRow tb = new TableRow();
     TableCell tc = new TableCell();

     DropDownList db = new DropDownList();
    db.Items.Add("Bangalore");`
    db.Items.Add("Mandya");
    db.Items.Add( "Hassan");

    tc.Controls.Add(db);
    tb.Controls.Add(tc);

   Table1.Controls.Add(tb);

   db.SelectedIndexChanged += db_SelectedIndexChanged;
   db.AutoPostBack = true;
   db_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null); // use this line, i hope it will work now.

  }

  private void db_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    label.text = "welcome";
  }
```

You can try this one.